# Apply working/staging changes directly to a commit

Tags: git

I made changes to some files. I realize that these changes would most appropriately be amended to a specific prior commit (e.g. HEAD~5, 5 commits back). In general, I can `git rebase` to that commit, perform an amend, and then return to HEAD. Is there any shortcut to simply apply a set of changes to a specific commit and still be located at HEAD when all the rebasing is completed?

Comment: You could commit to head, THEN do an interactive rebase to HEAD~6 or whatever and rearrange the commits so that your new one is right above the one you want to modify and then squash it... I think that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule here is, as [kcraigie noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516962/apply-working-staging-changes-directly-to-a-commit#comment54815844_33516962), to just make the commit "now", then use interactive rebase to move it and turn it into a squash or fixup.

Interactive rebase and commit can co-ordinate to support a feature where these can be "auto-squashed".  See the `--squash` and `--fixup` description in [the `git commit` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html).

The way this works is really very simple: a commit made with these options just has, as its commit message, the right string (it starts with `squash!` or `fixup!`, followed by the one line message from the commit you're fixing).  Then, when you later run `git rebase -i --autosquash`, the rebase code moves the `pick` line automatically, and automatically changes `pick` to `squash` or `fixup`, as directed.

(If you like, you can make the commit, then immediately run the rebase.)